# Loop and post value inside array-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this script that get JSON value from server and then post them on Fullcalendar, the extraction and post value works perfectly but the problem that sometimes I got more than one value on JSON result.

my code is below

```
.done(function (data) {
            var html = ""
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data[0].events)



            let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                // On charge le composant "dayGrid"
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
                //defaultView: 'listMonth',
                //local :'fr', //traduction,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,list'
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'aujourd\'hui',
                    month: 'Mois',
                    week: 'Semaine',
                    list: 'liste'
                },
                events: [

                    {
                        title: data[0].events.title,
                        start: data[0].events.start,
                        end: "2020-05-18 18:00:00"
                    },

                ],
                nowIndicator: true
            });
```

the `data` containe JSON result which is like below : 
[image]

what I want is this :

if the `data[i] > 1` how can I modify my code in order to display all the potential value and if there is another data at the same time and date then it is displayed also next to the first one

the part that needs to be modified is below

```
events: [

                        {
                            title: data[0].events.title,// 0 is first index, how to place i incrementation
                            start: data[0].events.start,
                            end: "2020-05-18 18:00:00"
                        },

                    ],
```

Any idea please ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data is an array, you can iterate over it like so:

```
.done(function (data) {
    var html = ""
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0].events)

    const events = data.map((row)=>{
        return {
            title: row.events.title,
            start: row.events.start,
            end: "2020-05-18 18:00:00"
        }
    })

    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        // On charge le composant "dayGrid"
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
        //defaultView: 'listMonth',
        //local :'fr', //traduction,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,list'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'aujourd\'hui',
            month: 'Mois',
            week: 'Semaine',
            list: 'liste'
        },
        events,
        nowIndicator: true
    });
```

Comment: Im glad it worked! If this answered your question, would you mind marking it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: yeah yeah sorry for that, see ya